# How to deal with stubbing new method with potential Nil class in Ruby and rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a situation where I stub the .new method of a class, but that makes it to return nil objects, and later those objects are needed, and I am not sure how to deal with it. Here is my rspec code:

```
describe ShopWorker do
  describe '#perform' do
    let(:worker) { ShopWorker.new }
    it 'creates a new instance of Shopper' do
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      expect(Shopper).to receive(:new).with(user)
      worker.perform(user.id)
    end
  end
end
```

And here is my Worker code:

```
class ShopWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(user_id)
    user = User.find(user_id)

    shopper = Shopper.new(user)
    shopper.start # This fails because Shopper.new returns NIL
  end
end
```

So, since I am stubbing the new method with `expect(Shopper).to receive(:new).with(user)`, then when in the worker it does shopper.start, that is nil, and therefore it breaks. How should I solve this? Ideally, I would like to test that a new instance of Shopper is done and also that the method start is called for that instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do:

1. Expect to receive `:new` but provide a return value (possibly a mock), using `and_return()`. The problem is that `to receive` has an implicit `and_return(nil)` unless you provide a return value explicitly.
2. Don't stub `:new`, let it do its job and expect `:start` on any `Shopper` instance: `expect_any_instance_of(Shopper).to receive(:start)`.
3. Ask yourself what value this test provides. The test knows a lot about the implementation, to a point where you always have to change both. What is the impact of `shopper.start`? Can you assert anything about the actual business value?

Comment: The 3rd point is really good. This test is just trying to find out that the Worker actually instantiates an object (which is who actually does all the job, and I have tested that in another part).